# How to cleanly factorize two almost similar functions

Tags: javascript

I have 2 very similar content of functions and I'd like to factorize cleanly the code by making it a single function but a few lines only differ, more precisely, one of them has 3 lines of code more than the others.

```
function doStuffForFacebook() { 
  var example = "toto"
  //about 7 lines of code

  resizeScale = 1
}

functiondoStuffforYoutube() {
  var example = "toto"
  //the VERY SAME 7 lines of code as those inside doStuffForFacebook()

  //the 3 lines which are different from above
  if ( typeof cryptoVideoX !== "undefined" && cryptoVideoX !== null && cryptoVideoX !== 0 ) {
     var vidRatio = cryptoVideoX / netVideoY;
  } else { //no crypto video add-on by source
      var vidRatio = netVideoRatio;
  }
  var manually_recalculated_width_to_have_full_screen_height_video = Math.round(vidRatio * winHeight);// fb only accepts rounded values
            $fbPlayer.attr('data-width', manually_recalculated_width_to_have_full_screen_height_video );

  resizeScale = 1
}
```

I'd really like to factorize as repeating all this long 7+ lines only for 1 small lines of difference seems improvable.

Is there a way recommended to do this, maybe using something similar to a callback which would enable to do something like?

```
function doStuffForFacebook() { 
  resizeVideo(null);//nil because here no callback is necessary
}

functiondoStuffforYoutube() {
  resizeVideo(addSomeCodeCallback);
}
function resizeVideo(callback) {
  var example = "toto"
  //the 7 lines of common CODE
  callback();          
  resizeScale = 1
}
function addSomeCodeCallback() {
  if ( typeof cryptoVideoX !== "undefined" && cryptoVideoX !== null && cryptoVideoX !== 0 ) {
     var vidRatio = cryptoVideoX / netVideoY;
  } else { //no crypto video add-on by source
      var vidRatio = netVideoRatio;
  }
  var manually_recalculated_width_to_have_full_screen_height_video = Math.round(vidRatio * winHeight);// fb only accepts rounded values
            $fbPlayer.attr('data-width', 
  manually_recalculated_width_to_have_full_screen_height_video );
}
```

i know I could but I'd rather not: create functions for what's before the  and another function for what's after as they're all more logical not split as they belong to large if/else blocks.

How to do this properly respecting javascript best practices ?

Comment: You wouldn't have 50 lines of code in a single function. Try to split that into multiple smaller functions, then it will become clear to you how you can do the rest, too.

Comment: sorry mistyped, it was 7 lines of code. Stll repeating EXACTLY the same lines of code twice seem not DRY enough=> i'd like to factorize if possible

Comment: Please also add the `//about 7 lines of code` it makes no sense to refactor code that one does not know.

Comment: Oh and `nil` is python (?) in js its `null` ...

Comment: hehe yes ruby reflex, just changed into null

Comment: `function about7LinesOfCode() {  //about 7 lines of code }` - done. Without context, that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a default empty function for your callback parameter:

```
function resizeVideo(callback = function(){}) {
  ...
  callback() 
  ...
}
```

Comment: ok, I thought callbacks could be the most appropriate approach but then for doStuffForFacebook() where there is no additional code, i can write resizeVideo(null) to show there is no additional callback to call or just using  resizeVideo() will make javascript understand there is no callback ?

Comment: The function prototype of resizeVideo defines a null function that will be used if not provided, as resizeVideo()